# deleting column by header value deletes all columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My code has (at least) 2 problems. Can anyone offer suggestions? I am trying to learn JavaScript so I would really prefer hints rather then completed code. My goal is to copy a sheet `Main` into a new sheet called `achievement` and remove all columns that do not have the word `achievement` in the first row.

it doesnt copy the values from sheet Main to sheet achievement (I am left with a blank doc in achievement.

When I manually paste the data the code deletes every column (instead of the ones not containing the word achievement)

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('STARTED');
  var search_term='achievement';
  var main=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Main');
  var cp=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(search_term);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(main.getName()+':'+cp.getName());
  main.copyTo(cp);

  var values = cp.getDataRange().getValues();

  var cell='';
  try{  
    //n=1 skip first col because it has titles as well as the first row
  for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
    cell = values[0][n] ; // 0 is the index of the first row.
    if(!cell.indexOf('achievement')>-1)
    {
      cp.deleteColumn(n);
      values = cp.getDataRange().getValues();
      n=1
    }
  }
  }catch(e)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(e+'val:col:'+cell+':'+n);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('DONE');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `values` is a 2-D array, an array of rows, each of them an array of cells (or columns). Your choice of looping range does not match the structure of this data:

```
for(n=1;n<values.length;++n){
```

This next line has the code equivalent of a double negative in it:

```
if(!cell.indexOf('achievement')>-1)
```

... so it will delete the wrong columns. Remember that when the target string isn't present, `indexOf()` will return `-1`.

And speaking of deleting columns, consider this:

```
cp.deleteColumn(n);
```

You're looking at pre-fetched data to determine what columns to delete, and deleting them from the spreadsheet. When you delete a column, all columns to the right of the deleted one(s) get new column indexes. In other words, the +/-1 relationship between the pre-fetched arrays and the spreadsheet columns changes.

You can avoid that by looping down instead of up.

Otherwise, try stepping through each line in the debugger, validating changes on the spreadsheet. It looks like your new sheet should be populated by `main.copyTo(cp);`, so check that first.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 function testFunction()
    {
    var search_term = 'achievement';
    var mainsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Main');
     //make a copy of the main sheet and set a name.
    var values = mainsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var columns = mainsheet.getDataRange().getNumColumns();
//Check for each cell value and take the column numbers to an array.

      // Instead of deleting each column from the sheet evrytime in the loop, try modifying the array and then update the sheet with those values one time.   

        }
```

I can provide the working code if you want.

Hope that helps!